# Sinch: How do I set the SINCall variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sinch

I'm having a bit of confusion on how to properly create a SINCall object. I understand that SINCall is a type protocol, and in swift I tried to create it as such:

`var _call: SINCall?`

When I try to call, my app crashes because the _call is nil.

However, if I do add SINCall to the list of protocols next to SINCallDelegate, and SINCallClientDelegate, I get the error that I'm not conforming to the SINCall protocol.

```
class CallViewController: UIViewController, SINCallDelegate, SINCallClientDelegate {

    var userName: String? {
        didSet {

        }
    }
    var recepientUser: String? {
        didSet {

        }
    }

    var _call: SINCall?

    var appKey = "xxx"
    var appSecret = "xxx"
    var host = "xxx"

    var client: SINClient {
        return Sinch.clientWithApplicationKey(appKey, applicationSecret: appSecret, environmentHost: host, userId: userName!)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Lock and load")

    client.callClient().delegate = self
    client.setSupportCalling(true)
    client.start()
    client.startListeningOnActiveConnection()

    callUser()
}

func callUser() {
    self._call = client.callClient().callUserWithId(self.recepientUser!)
    self._call!.delegate = self
}

func client(client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {
    call.delegate = self
    self._call = call
    self._call!.answer()
}

// callDidProgress, callDidEstablish, callDidEnd implemented below ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the client started when you make the call, it can take a few seconds so you should probably start the the client in the app delegate when its launched, and then when the client is started you can do a call, you probably get nil now because the client is not started

Comment: Appreciate the response! I created the call controller programmatically in my other controller (Main Controller), and I presented the call controller with my username and remote user name set. Perhaps I should start the client in my app delegate instead of the viewdidload() inside my call view controller class.

Comment: If you want to recieve calls that is the way to go, if you only want to make call you could start it in the view controller but you have to wait for it to start before you make a call